# Azure Data Factory Copy Data to Snowflake

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

I am writing a number of ADF Pipelines that copy data from a SQL server to Snowflake **through a Blob storage stage**.

I am wondering if all of the data will land in Snowflake synchronously (at the same time) or if small batches of the same ADF pipeline run may hit the table at different times.

The reason I am wondering is that I have a secondary process which picks up the "most recent" data and runs transformations. I want to ensure that it doesn't pick up a partial ADF load.

Comment: Check to see if a single job is executing multiple COPY statements in Snowflake.  If it is executing a single COPY statement (which it should be), then all of the data will be loaded at one time.  There is no such thing as a "partial load" in Snowflake in that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If source data store and format are natively supported by Snowflake COPY command`(COPY INTO <table>)`, you can use the Copy activity to directly copy from source to Snowflake

As per your configuration I assume here snowflake acts as sink, here the reference document which gives you more insight about the command format to perform the copy activity either in direct copy to snowflake or built-in staged copy to snowflake

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-snowflake#snowflake-as-sink

Comment: @Ryan Moore , if the above solution was helpful ? If so could please mark accept the answer as solution. This could help other community users who have similar query in the future